# Create a Matrix that contains lists in Netlogo

Tags: matrix, netlogo

I need to create a Matrix that contains a list of turtles in each position, is it possible in netlogo?

If it will be a 2x2 matrix and if would use print matrix:pretty-print-text m It would looks like:

```
=>
```

[[ [(turtle 1) (turtle 2) (turtle n)]  [(turtle 1) (turtle 2) (turtle n)]
[ [(turtle 1) (turtle 2) (turtle n)]  [(turtle 1) (turtle 2) (turtle n)] ]]

Comment: What is your motivation for wanting to use a matrix and not just do it entirely with lists and agentsets?

Answer (score 0):

Well, according to the manual, looking up matrix extension
" A matrix is a mutable 2-dimensional array containing only numbers."
So no you cannot do exactly what you posted, which is a list of agents.

But since turtles have unique "who" variables,  you CAN make a matrix
with those WHO values in the correct positions, assuming
(1) you make sure only one turtle can be in a given location at one time,
(2) I'm not sure what you put in your matrix if there are no turtles there.   Maybe a flag like -1 ? That's up to you.